# I need to know where I add the code add_meta_box()

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a new meta box in the admin worpress using `add_meta_box` 
The intention is to make an image gallery, similar to what the plugin uses woocomerce:

> ( http://docs.woothemes.com/document/adding-product-images-and-galleries/ )

Accept help and county, as it is the first time I try this.

But first, I need to know where I add the code `add_meta_box ();`

Thanks attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `add_meta_box()` in `functions.php` or in external file and include it into `functions.php`

please check the codex page

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: the functions.php file located in wp-includes folder or the functions.php file located in the theme folder in question?

Comment: in the theme folder you you should not edit anything in the core files of wordpress in wp-includes or wp-admin you always edit in the theme